# Populate email programatically with a From field in a POP3 server

Tags: node.js, outlook, pop3, poplib

I have a POP3 email account (Outlook) and I am able to retrieve emails from it programatically using poplib library (NodeJS).

Now I would like to populate emails in the server programatically: generating a new email where I can specify the "From", "To", "Subject", etc. And making it available in this POP3 account. I don't mean sending an email to that account, but generating an email as if it had been received in that account.

How can I do that? I am open to use any programming language / library.

Comment: I can suggest to dig here: https://nodemailer.com/about/

Comment: @Lazyexpert interesting, but I would like to set up From and To fields to values that are not necessarily the Outlook POP3 account. NodeMailer seems to require to have that account in the To. Any way to generate this in the POP3 server without sending an actual email?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that: POP3 is a **retrieval** protocol, you cannot upload message like you can in IMAP4 (both upload and download) or SMTP (message submission only).